# SSL Certificate error while doing a request via python

Tags: python, ssl, certificate

Iam trying to make an API call to a HTTPS url:

```
response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=None, verify=True)
```

and Iam facing the following error. It works fine when i invoke the API via cUrl or Postman...

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py",
>   line 601, in urlopen
>           chunked=chunked)   File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py",
>   line 346, in _make_request
>           self._validate_conn(conn)   File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py",
>   line 850, in _validate_conn
>           conn.connect()   File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py",
>   line 326, in connect
>           ssl_context=context)   File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py",
>   line 329, in ssl_wrap_socket
>           return context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)   File
>   "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\contrib\pyopenssl.py",
>   line 448, in wrap_socket
>           raise ssl.SSLError('bad handshake: %r' % e) ssl.SSLError: ("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines',
>   'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')],)",)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py",
>   line 440, in send
>           timeout=timeout   File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py",
>   line 639, in urlopen
>           _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])   File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py",
>   line 388, in increment
>           raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause)) urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError:
>   HTTPSConnectionPool(host='freshdesk.freshsales.io', port=443): Max
>   retries exceeded with url:
>   /api/sales_accounts/1000080286/conversations.json?include=email_conversation_recipients,all,targetable,phone_numbe,phone_calle,note,user
>   (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines',
>   'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify
>   failed')],)",),))

I tried by specifying **verify=False** .Still there is error

> C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py:858:
>   InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding
>   certificate verification is strongly advised. See:
>   https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
>   InsecureRequestWarning) Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\contrib\pyopenssl.py",
>   line 441, in wrap_socket
>           cnx.do_handshake()   File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\OpenSSL\SSL.py",
>   line 1716, in do_handshake
>           self._raise_ssl_error(self._ssl, result)   File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\OpenSSL\SSL.py",
>   line 1456, in _raise_ssl_error
>           _raise_current_error()   File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\OpenSSL_util.py",
>   line 54, in exception_from_error_queue
>           raise exception_type(errors) OpenSSL.SSL.Error: [('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify
>   failed')]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py",
>   line 601, in urlopen
>           chunked=chunked)   File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py",
>   line 346, in _make_request
>           self._validate_conn(conn)   File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py",
>   line 850, in _validate_conn
>           conn.connect()   File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py",
>   line 326, in connect
>           ssl_context=context)   File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py",
>   line 329, in ssl_wrap_socket
>           return context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)   File
>   "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\contrib\pyopenssl.py",
>   line 448, in wrap_socket
>           raise ssl.SSLError('bad handshake: %r' % e) ssl.SSLError: ("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines',
>   'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')],)",)

Any ideas on how i can circumvent this error ? I Browsed through various questions here but could not find a solution for this. The URL administrator also confirmed that the server certificates are valid so i feel this has definitely got to do something with some conflicting package installation.

Here's my pip freeze list of packages:

```
C:\Users\user\python>pip freeze
asn1crypto==0.23.0
attrs==16.3.0
Automat==0.5.0
beautifulsoup4==4.5.3
bleach==1.5.0
bs4==0.0.1
certifi==2017.7.27.1
cffi==1.11.2
chardet==3.0.4
chargebee==2.1.8
colorama==0.3.7
constantly==15.1.0
cryptography==2.1.1
cssselect==1.0.1
decorator==4.0.11
entrypoints==0.2.2
html5lib==0.9999999
idna==2.6
incremental==16.10.1
ipykernel==4.5.2
ipython==5.3.0
ipython-genutils==0.1.0
ipywidgets==5.2.2
Jinja2==2.9.5
jsonschema==2.6.0
jupyter==1.0.0
jupyter-client==5.0.0
jupyter-console==5.1.0
jupyter-core==4.3.0
lxml==3.7.3
MarkupSafe==0.23
mistune==0.7.3
nbconvert==5.1.1
nbformat==4.3.0
notebook==4.4.1
numpy==1.12.0
pandas==0.19.2
pandocfilters==1.4.1
parsel==1.1.0
pickleshare==0.7.4
prompt-toolkit==1.0.13
pyasn1==0.2.3
pyasn1-modules==0.0.8
pycparser==2.18
PyDispatcher==2.0.5
Pygments==2.2.0
PyJWT==1.5.0
pyOpenSSL==17.3.0
PySocks==1.6.7
python-dateutil==2.6.0
pytz==2016.10
pyzmq==16.0.2
qtconsole==4.2.1
queuelib==1.4.2
requests==2.18.4
selenium==3.0.2
service-identity==16.0.0
simplegeneric==0.8.1
six==1.11.0
testpath==0.3
tornado==4.4.2
traitlets==4.3.2
twilio==6.0.0
urllib3==1.22
w3lib==1.17.0
wcwidth==0.1.7
widgetsnbextension==1.2.6
win-unicode-console==0.5
zope.interface==4.3.3
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally figured out that it was a Network issue. Took this up with my company's IT team and they resolved it by doing some IP whitelisting.